# Attempting to access data after fetching with custom hook not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I had a basic useFetch hook implementation that defined a fetchData function which would setData to some JSON if successful, then I would called it on useEffect with no dependencies and the hook returned the stateful data value. I found that this was not ideal, because I wanted to fetch things dynamically on events.

So Instead, I changed the useFetch hook to simply return the fetchData function reference along with the data, and no longer call fetchData inside the hook.

```
const useFetch = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async (url) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      if (response.ok) {
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setData(jsonData);
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  return { fetchData, data };
};
```

This however introduced problems where I use this hook. I've never used this pattern before so I don't really know what I'm doing, but I'm unable to do stuff with the data value after calling the fetch function. Here's basically how I'm using the hook in another functional component:

```
  const [displayedItems, setDisplayedItems] = useState([]);

  const { fetchData, data } = useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(urlGoesHere);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDisplayedItems(data);
    console.log(displayedItems);
  }, [data]);
```

This is ugly, and it doesn't work. I tried putting them all in one useEffect, but that also doesn't work. Sometimes, when I live reload in CRA, I can see data being logged, but typically when my page loads, data just stays undefined. So I basically created another problem by changing useFetch from actually using the fetch function (which has the downside of not being able to be called in my regular functions and event callbacks), and now I can't seem to even render anything.

I'm pretty new to React and async stuff so I'd appreciate a response that takes that into consideration. If there's a much better pattern for the kind of thing I'm trying to do, I'd love to hear it, but I'd like to keep it in vanilla react land, so no libraries, etc. Again, the reason I'm returning a reference to the fetch function is because I want to be able to use it in callbacks and stuff.

Thanks all!

Edit: It sort of works if I check for the truthiness of data in the second useEffect, but anyhow, can this implementation be better?

```
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(urlGoesHere);
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
           setDisplayedItems(data);
           console.log(displayedItems);
        }
      }, [data]);
```

Does this mean I have to use 2 whole useEffects every time I want to fetch something on load?

Comment: Is this an exercise for learning? Other implementations of "`useFetch`" hooks already exist (e.g. [`useSWR`](https://swr.vercel.app/))

Comment: @jsejcksn pretty much exactly that. I'm aware that it's not practical, but trying to keep it vanilla for my first project using React so I can understand React a little more. I looked at SWR at some point though so thanks for reminding me. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can return more properties than just the data from the hook in order to help you make an informed choice about what and when to render. A common pattern in many simple `useFetch` hooks like the one you've asked about is to return `data`, `error`, and `isLoading`, so that you can declaratively render the UI you intend to based on a combination of those states, still eagerly fetching the data after the component first renders.

If you need more control over when the data is fetched (e.g. you mentioned in reaction to an "event"), just use the hook in a child component, and conditionally render that child component based on your "event". Below is a typical example of a simplistic `useFetch` hook (which you can see working in the code snippet):

> Here's [a link to just the hook in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBRAZltBjGAGjlTQGUYBDGNAXziyghDgHIo1KDWBuAWABQgmAE8waOADE0MPAAsAItUoAeACoA+OAF5EguHAAmygFxw1cAD4kAdobRZgNtIf4CDaKEyhmMX6Fa29o7OrvpwwCgAMhCUhk4A5mYARhAQADacNm60boJYSDYEwBA2JOjSsnJw6jq2ANY2EADuNhoAFEhQ6WYoMFCJAJRmlfJKVOpaCOF4pX1wANrGVMToMOOUALp1pBTUaLXWhcFOLh2DbgazNvMLnt6rMn7e27q7VDQqzwFHdg6nhnOlzg11ukRicUSjxgAElorF4jYEq9yuQPgdUhksh0sJR0ugLoJwqRsLgCO12oMdFNwlc5vAuHVnM04ABBVKwADCpX6GUyUEpeXcBhB9IYMjGyjqlBQIiKcEp1L0wpFcDWcIhiIS7X6SDQhJVIv6ImVqtVoPgHBQkBuEl0lGalGA8FwVU63WICBQwASNjxZi4ADpvb68bQDWaRcAsAqAIRWm3oQMQepUmByJgs5lwb4CigDJHtBNzNDBj6oQYRyOim6WtAoJDpeD2x3OuDF22BgBWKFKipl5mBkbWGyL9cbMCrw6e-gFx3+oSnItotJFeGo8gVaAAHmZCo0WjYqdNDaq1rn2juIrXKEU0BAY7m4AB+OBXszZi-5xKX7eVpcGCup5qjIGoIj+uL4vqQ5wLkRKGq6kpUIKq4cDAXRlIq2haEGlAcjAKHCrQxALF06TQhs0K5tCYGQkimwGuEaEYYgyyUMQ9zQMQ4LgUicECEBQA), which you can use to access and copy the transpiled JavaScript if you can't or don't want to use TypeScript.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

/**
 * The following line is here because this Stack Overflow snippet uses the
 * UMD module for React. In your code, you'd use the commented `import` lines
 * below it.
 */
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
// import type {ReactElement} from 'react';

type FetchData<T> = {
  data: T | undefined;
  error: Error | undefined;
  isLoading: boolean;
};

function useFetch <T = unknown>(url: string): FetchData<T> {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | undefined>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | undefined>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ac = new AbortController();

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {signal: ac.signal});
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(String(response.status));
        const result = await response.json() as T;
        setData(result);
        setError(undefined);
      }
      catch (ex: unknown) {
        setError(ex instanceof Error ? ex : new Error(String(ex)));
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => ac.abort();
  }, [url, setData, setError, setIsLoading]);

  return {data, error, isLoading};
}

type User = { username: string };

function Example (): ReactElement {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  const {data, error, isLoading} = useFetch<User[]>(url);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      {
        isLoading
          ? (<div>Loading users...</div>)
          : null
      }
      {
        error
          ? (<div>There was an error loading the data ({error.message})</div>)
          : null
      }
      {
        data
          ? (
            <ul>
              {data.map(({username}, index) => (
                <li key={`${index}-${username}`}>{username}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )
          : null
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?